# Auto Music Tagging Software

Tags: mp3, music, media

Is there any software out there that will completely and automatically clean and organize a music library?  I have tried MediaMonkey, Songbird, Foobar, iTunes, TuneUp and various other programs I have heard of but nothing quite does the job, or just makes things way worse.

There are a few programs out there I can't remember the name of that analyze the song and look up the tags, but even these seem limited in overall functionality or still require a ton of user involvement.

Basically a program that will automatically tag, regroup, rename, find albumn art and remove duplicates with as little user involvement as possible.  Doesn't have to be free, I'd probably pay quite a bit for a program that could do all of this reliably.

Here is a start...

http://lifehacker.com/5266613/six-best-mp3-tagging-tools

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You want [MusicBrainz Picard](http://musicbrainz.org/doc/PicardDownload).

Any music tagging software will require some user involvement to function 100% reliably. This is just due to the messy nature of music distribution. But the actual amount of involvement is up to you. If you really want to take the risk, you can just click "ok" in Picard (or any other tool) and let it decide everything for you. It will probably work fine, but there's a chance it will choose non-ideal tags for an album or two. Any software you find that seems like it doesn't require any user involvement has the same risk.