# Update music files with track information in Windows Media Player

Tags: windows-7, windows, windows-media-player, media

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [Auto Music Tagging Software](https://superuser.com/questions/181126/auto-music-tagging-software)

Is there some way I can get WMP to retrieve track information from its internet sources and update tracks in my CD rips? I have several where the tracks are just Track01.wav or Track01.wma, or *.mp3 etc. and I would like to update these tracks to reflect their proper track info.

Alternately, is there any other way I can do this?

Comment: possible duplicate of [Auto Music Tagging Software](http://superuser.com/questions/181126/auto-music-tagging-software) also see [Auto-tagging MP3s](http://superuser.com/questions/95425/auto-tagging-mp3s) - WMP is not good at tagging optical media "albums" that aren't on the original media.  WAV's are limited in their available metadata (tag) fields (perhaps convert them to MP3?).

Comment: Hmm, yes, I seem to recall WMP (and others) uses a hash value from the disc as a key to access album info. Maybe time to write a little util, as I am quite prepared to source the album info myself; I just want to automate updating the track files.

Comment: Check out Tag&Rename, and Picard MusicBrainz in the linked questions/answers, they are my favs. :) Once the files themselves are tagged properly, then WMP will deal with them better.